# Apache Pig : UDF : ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias fileterd

Tags: apache-pig

Wrote a custom UDF in pig by name `vaidateUser` which validates usernames.

```
 public class ValidateUser extends FilterFunc {
       public Boolean exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
           // custom validation code 
       }
 }
```

The class is a part of default package and is part of `pig_udfs.jar`.

This JAR is used in the pig script : `validateUsers.pig`

```
 REGISTER 'pig_udfs.jar';

 users = load 'users.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (user:chararray);

 validUsers = filter users by ValidateUser(user);

 dump validUsers;
```

Tried executing the script using :

```
 pig -x local validateusers.pig
```

Getting error as below, any inputs/ thoughts on resolving this would be appreciated !

Pig Stack Trace:

---

```
ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias fileterd

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias fileterd
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:615)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:303)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:90)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:500)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't face any issue the `custom filter UDF` and its working fine, Can you try this?. 
In the below example, i will filter out all the names which is not equal to `"test"`.

**users.txt**

```
test
mike
test
john
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER 'pig_udfs.jar';

users = load 'users.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (user:chararray);
validUsers = filter users by ValidateUser(user);
dump validUsers;
```

**ValidateUser.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class ValidateUser extends FilterFunc {
        @Override
                public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
                        try {
                                String str = (String)input.get(0);
                                return (!str.equals("test"));
                        }
                        catch (IOException ee) {
                                throw ee;
                        }
                }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(john)
(mike)
```

**Makesure that you have set piggybank.jar in the classpath**

```
> javac ValidateUser.java
> jar -cvf pig_udfs.jar ValidateUser.class
> pig -x local validateusers.pig
```